# How many threads is robocopy really using?

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to copy a huge number of small files (30M x 150k) from one server to another over a network, like this:

```
robocopy sourceDir \\1.2.3.4\destDir /s /MT:32 /NP /LOG:d:\robocopy.log
```

The copy is working, but I see that according to Task Manager, robocopy.exe is only running two threads -- not the 32 I specified. Anybody know why?

Comment: if you don't specify the MT option does it run the default of 8 threads (current version)?  What OS?

Answer (score 3):

Opening up resource monitor on the target machine under Disk Activity you can see what files are currently being written to disc, ie how many threads are currently in use. `/MT:32` uses 32 threads as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it only uses two threads when it's figuring out what to copy, then spun up another 32 once it got busy copying files. I should test this again to verify, but I haven't yet.